# Getting value of tag referenced by id ref

Tags: xml, xslt, transformation, idref

I'm trying to get a value of a tag of an element referenced by idref.

```
<ksiazka id="k2">
    <title> title 1 </title>
    <wydawnictwo idref="wyd1"/>
</ksiazka>

<wyd id="wyd1">
    <name>Zielona Sowa</name>
</wyd>
```

To get title of < ksiazka > all I have to do is

```
<xsl:template match="ksiazka">
    <xsl:value-of select "./title"/>
```

But how to get < name > out of < wyd >? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XSLT has a [build-in mechanism](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#key) to resolve cross-references. Start by defining a **key** at the top level of your stylesheet as:

```
<xsl:key name="pub" match="wyd" use="@id" />
```

Then you can use:

```
<xsl:value-of select="key('pub', wydawnictwo/@idref)/name"/>
```

to get the corresponding `wyd/name` from the context of `ksiazka`.

---

See a demo here: http://xsltransform.net/94AbWBE

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured out how to do it.

```
<xsl:key name = "wydawnictwoKEY" match= "wyd" use = "@id" />

<xsl:template match="wydawnictwo">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:value-of select="key('wydawnictwoKEY', @idref)/name"/>
        </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

and then

```
    <xsl:apply-templates select="wydawnictwo"/>
```